# Convert GEE object to image?

Tags: google-earth-engine, convert, printing, reducers, addlayer

I have tried to calculate the average precipitation in each cropland. However, it seems I have a problem generating a map of the final result. It does show that "Expression does not evaluate to an image". Anyone can suggest me, please?

```
//clip GPM by krabi boundary
//var clipToCol = function(image){
 // return image.clip(table);
//};

//clip GPM by oil palm plot inkrabi boundary
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(table2);
};


//upload GPM monthly rainfall analysis
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06').filter(
    ee.Filter.date('2014-12-01', '2015-01-01')).map(clipToCol);

// Select the max precipitation and mask out low precipitation values.
var precipitation = dataset.select('precipitation').max();
var mask = precipitation.gt(0.25);
//var precipitation = precipitation.updateMask(mask);

var palette = [ 
  '000096','0064ff', '00b4ff', '33db80', '9beb4a',
  'ffeb00', 'ffb300', 'ff6400', 'eb1e00', 'af0000'
];
var precipitationVis = {min: 0.0, max: 1.5, palette: palette};
Map.addLayer(precipitation, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
Map.setCenter(98.797816, 8.52186, 20);

//add krabi boundary
var styling = {color: 'red'};
Map.addLayer(table.style(styling));

//Export GPM to drives
Export.image.toDrive({  
 image: precipitation.clipToCollection(table),  
 description: 'GPM_krabi_Dec2014',  
 scale: 7,  
 region: ee.Feature(table.first()).bounds(),  
 fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',  
 maxPixels: 1e12,  
 formatOptions: {  
    cloudOptimized: true  
  },
  skipEmptyTiles: true
});

//add oil palm plot in krabi boundary
var styling = {color: 'green'};
Map.addLayer(table2.style(styling));

// convert oil palm plot in krabi to the format of geometry
var Krabi_Plot = ee.FeatureCollection(table2).geometry()
Map.addLayer(Krabi_Plot);

//convert the unit of GPM from mm/hr to mm/month in December 2014
var GPMDec14 = precipitation.multiply(744);
Map.addLayer(GPMDec14, {min: 0, max: 2000}, 'GPM_DEC14_monthly');

//calculate the averaged rainfall in each plot by zonal statistic (group mean reducer function)
//then resampling to 1 km 
var GPMDec14byPlot = GPMDec14.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry:Krabi_Plot,
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 2000
});

// Print the result
print(GPMDec14byPlot,'GPMDec14byPlot');

//show the raster of average GPM by plot in December 2014
//var AvgGPMDec14byplot = GPMDec14byPlot.sum();
var AvgGPMDec14byplot = ee.Image(GPMDec14byPlot);
Map.addLayer(AvgGPMDec14byplot,{},'GPMbyplot');
```

Let me also share the asset I have used in this script
for table1 https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/natnaphat/krabi
for table2 https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/natnaphat/Krabi_plot

Comment: The error you are getting results from your attempt to plot a dictionary of one value as an image! and your code raise many questions about what you are trying to accomplish! can you clarify what is your objective and the desired final output?
your precipitation data presents one month at >10km2 spatial resolution, so the collection is one mosaic image and average mean is either to be calculated per field resulting in one value per field, or for the entire area resulting in single value (as you seem to attempt in your code with multiple error)

Comment: Hi, I would like to average the amount of precipitation in each plot and export that plot in Geotiff.

Comment: The average amount of precipitation in each plot in your case (for single image with single band) is a single value per plot, how do you plan to use this in Geotiff format!?